# Can anyone clarify this? "Block pool storage is not partitioned..."

Tags: hadoop

I'm reading Hadoop - The Definitive Guide by Tom White, 4th edition, where he writes,

> "Block pool storage is not partitioned, however, so datanodes register
>   with each namenode in the cluster and store blocks from multiple block
>   pools."

Can anyone clarify that? Specifically, if...

```
NameNodeA: blockpool for DataNode1 and DataNode2
NameNodeB: blockpool for DataNode3 and DataNode4
```

...does NameNodeB store NodeNameA's blockpool? That seems wasteful since the author previously wrote that "namenodes do not communicate with one another."

Update: After reviewing comments here and re-reading, it seems to work like this: you can partition the namespace into federated namenodes, which **manage** a partition (e.g., /user) but nonetheless **contain** the entire namespace (e.g., /user /foo /bar).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this is how HDFS Federation works, innit? All datanodes are connected to a single namespace called blockpool to which all namenodes have access. So name nodes don't have to connect to each other, they just need to access the pool and all namenodes will have metadata for the FS.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://www.slideshare.net/huguk/hdfs-federation-hadoop-summit2011) explains the architecture in more detail. It was created by one of the Hadoop committers at Yahoo. I mistakenly thought there was 1 namespace, but in fact, you can have multiple namespaces.